# How to optomize laoding 50 or more textareas with TinyMCE? Webpage takes a few seconds to load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I'm using bootstrap modals for every textarea, so is there a way to use ajax or jquery to make the textarea active only after I click the button to open the modal? I also have php variables populating the default textarea text.

Edit:

I just discovered that you can use the "inline" feature (which succesfully removed slow page load). But how do you submit your form with no inputs? Here's the code you're supposed to use:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="myeditablediv">Click here to edit the second section of content!</div>
</form>
```

Comment: ..... Yes probably! A littel more information about the actual code would be useful to assist in giving an answer rather than an opinion

Comment: What you have done so far to achieve it ?

Comment: add preloader and when last init remove )

Comment: What do you mean by preloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with Froala html editor instead and this solved the issue. No load time with over 100 editors loaded. And much easier to use.